# Jqgrid search results pagination with Spring 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jqgrid, spring-roo

I have several jqgrids running and all are functioning fine. However, when I do a search, I am only displaying ten search results per page. Whenever there are more than ten results, clicking on page two has no effect on the grid. Here is one of my controller actions, pay particular attention to the if satatement where search is true....

**EDIT**

I think I may have found a clue as to what may be causing my issue. You see I have several subgrids under the main grid. In terms of my java code I have **object-A** which has a list of **object-B**
, thus **A** has a subgrid of **B**. The way i am building up the json string to feed to the grid is by iterating over the list of **B** contained in **A**. I did not write a query of some kind to say order by, and limit the results etc.

So i guess the real question should be how to build a finder on a collection so that the contents can be arranged and ordered as i wish?

Here is the action I am calling for one of my entities described as **B** above. Pay particular attention to where i said **person.getContacts()**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "contactjsondata/{pId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String contactjsondata(@PathVariable("pId") Long personId, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    Person person = Person.findPerson(personId);  
    String column = "id";
if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("sidx") != null){
    column = httpServletRequest.getParameter("sidx");
}
String orderType = "DESC";
if(httpServletRequest.getParameter("sord") != null){
    orderType = httpServletRequest.getParameter("sord").toUpperCase();
}
int page = 1;
if(Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("page")) >= 1){
    page = Integer.parseInt(httpServletRequest.getParameter("page"));
}
int limitAmount = 10;
int limitStart = limitAmount*page - limitAmount;
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>(person.getContacts());        
double tally = Math.ceil(contacts.size()/10.0d);
int totalPages = (int)tally;
int records = contacts.size();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("{\"page\":\"").append(page).append("\", \"records\":\"").append(records).append("\", \"total\":\"").append(totalPages).append("\", \"rows\":[");
boolean first = true;
for (Contact c: contacts) {
    sb.append(first ? "" : ",");
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    }
    sb.append(String.format("{\"id\":\"%s\", \"cell\":[\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\"]}",c.getId(), c.getId(), c.getContactType().getName() ,c.getContactValue()));
}
sb.append("]}"); 
return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your jsp/UI page code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue with pagination you need to replace the following block of code

```
for (Contact c: contacts) {
    sb.append(first ? "" : ",");
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    }
    sb.append(String.format("{\"id\":\"%s\", \"cell\":[\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\"]}",c.getId(), c.getId(), c.getContactType().getName() ,c.getContactValue()));
}
```

with:

```
for (int i=limitStart; i<Math.min(records, limitStart+limitAmount); i++){
    Contact c = contacts[i];
    sb.append(first ? "" : ",");
    if (first) {
       first = false;
    }
    sb.append(String.format("{\"id\":\"%s\", \"cell\":[\"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\"]}",c.getId(), c.getId(), c.getContactType().getName() ,c.getContactValue()));
}
```

Another option is using loadonce:true to let the jqGrid handle pagination and sorting. In this case you don't need to make changes described above